# Получение html кода страницы на js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Я делаю запрос на сайт чтобы получить html код:

```js
request('https://example.com', function (error, response, body) {
    console.error('error:', error);
    console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
    console.log('body:', body);
});
```

Hо, в большинстве своём, страница состоит из скриптов на js.

Можно ли с помощью js или node js получить html код, который будет после того, как сработают скрипты?

Comment: хотелось бы сайт получитыб и то что интересует узнатб

Comment: @Vadim Я пытаюсь получить html код страницы в твиттере для того чтобы выводить последний твит и некоторую информацию о пользователе. До 2 июня с помощью request мне приходил нормальный html код, без скриптов, но сейчас я получаю код состоящий из одних скриптов. Я знаю что можно отслеживать последний твит с помощью модуля twit, но вот работает он долго.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно. Запросом вы получаете статический файл, который надо затем обработать браузерным движком. Можете воспользоваться headless браузером в библиотеке [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/README.md). Собственно, это одна из главных задач, которую решает библиотека - парсинг SPA.